# iPhone:Adding multiple nsdictionaries into NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

I need to add multiple NSDictionaries into an NSArray to get a JSON message.I want to get this string.

This is my code:

```
for (int i=0;i<[ids count]; i++) 
    {



    [dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",personName] forKey:@"customerName"];

NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:cartDict]; 
[dict setObject:array forKey:@"OrderDetails"];


}
    NSString *request1 = [dict JSONRepresentation];


    //convert object to data
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[request1 UTF8String] length:[request1 length]];
    //NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:req options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];

    //print out the data contents
    json1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData
                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just changing the values in the *same instance* of the cartDict. If you want to have more than one cartDict in your array, alloc and init a new NSDictionary and then add that to the array (don't forget to release after if you aren't using ARC!).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I did what you said,but how could I add multiple cartDict into NSArray.Could you please elaborate.

Comment: As long as you create a new instance for each one you add to your NSArray, then that will sort it. The problem is that each time through the loop you are just changing the value in the same instance